# Is there a Gtk3 Widget that can display text as a terminal does?

Tags: c, terminal, gtk, gtk3

My C program running from a terminal display a red "Hello World" when coding this line below

```
printf("\x1B[31mHello World\033[0m");
```

I am hoping to the able to include the "\x1B[31mHello World\033[0m" in a buffer and have a widget displaying the text with colours like the terminal does.

Is there such a widget that can do that? Or any particular way to achieve that?

TextView just prints out the character as we see them.

This will save me a lot of re-coding.

Answer (score 2):

[`VteTerminal`](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.50/VteTerminal.html) is the GTK widget used in GNOME to emulate the terminal. Feeding your text into it with `vte_terminal_feed()` should give you the colored output you're looking for.

However this is a full-blown emulator that requires GNOME and may be an overkill for your needs. Using it may also lead to many unintended consequences. In the end you may decide to implement your own simple parser that would just handle colors.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it is a bit of an overkill. I'll have to rewrite my functions using TextView with tags then.